# Process multiple components in same way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a class in Unity which can have multiple types of components. And I want to process those components in a predefined way-> which translates to : I have a method body in mind which I don't want to change for different components.

But as interfaces can't have method body, I am unable use multiple interfaces in the same class acting in a similar way but differing according to their components.

I know I am effectively talking about multiple inheritance in C#, but is there a way to implement such a concept in unity engine?

I want something like this

```
public interface IProcessableComponent<T> where T : Component
{
    void Process();
}

public class ProcessableComponentsBase : IProcessableComponent<Rigidbody>, IProcessableComponent<Collider2D>
{
    public void Process()
    {

    }
}
```

But instead of Process having a body that can be changed in implementation. I want that behavior to remained unchanged.

Comment: Can you show some code? I don't clearly understand what you want.

Comment: Maybe you want to use generics? But there's clearly some (pseudo)code required to make your intentions clearer

Comment: Let me just update the post with a snippet

Comment: What are you want to do with components? And how are you want to call your Process method?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand rightly, you need something like this:

```
public interface IProcessableComponent
{
    void Process(Vector3 position);
}

public abstract class ProcessableComponentBase : MonoBehaviour, IProcessableComponent
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 holdedVector;
    public Vector3 HoldedVector { get { return holdedVector; } protected set { holdedVector = value; } }
    public virtual void Process(Vector3 newVector)
    {
        HoldedVector = newVector;
    }
}

public class ComponentA : ProcessableComponentBase
{
}

public class ComponentB : ProcessableComponentBase
{
}

public class TestComponentProcessing : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        var components = GetComponents<IProcessableComponent>();

        foreach(var entry in components)
        {
            entry.Process(Vector3.zero);
        }
    }
}
```

If you show what you want to do, i can edit my answer.